# Allow external editor to save file in app's local folder

Tags: c++, uwp

I have files in the app's [LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) which I want to allow user to be able to edit using an external editor and save the changes right on the file. I use `LaunchFileAsync` to launch

```
StorageFile^ file;
auto options = ref new Windows::System::LauncherOptions();
options->DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
create_task(Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchFileAsync(file, options));
```

For instance, when `file` is some `*.txt` file, it is expected that the user should be able to choose to edit it with Notepad and overwrite the file. Unfortunately, this is not the behavior observed. What I get is an error when attempting to save:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

though I can do **Save as** a new file right in the app's `LocalFolder`. Process hacking show that the file is opened by `smartscreen.exe`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you want to tag `C#` instead of `c++`?

Comment: @Spencer Well, I need to do it in `C++`.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't C++/CLI?  Because that particular blend of C++ and .NET syntax looks like C++/CLI, from what little I know of it.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. As the error said, the file you want to launch might be used by another process. The code you've posted is right, I'd suggest you find which process is using the file and end the task before testing.